# gRPC intermittently has high delays

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, grpc

I have a server app (C# with .Net 5) that exposes a gRPC bi-directional endpoint. This endpoint takes in a binary stream in which the server analyzes and produces responses that are sent back to the gRPC response stream.

Each file being sent over gRPC is few megabytes and it takes few minutes for the gRPC call to complete streaming (without latency). With latencies, this time increases sometimes by 50%.

On the client, I have 2 tasks (`Task.Run`) running, one streaming the file from the clients' file system using `FileStream`, other reading responses from the server (gRPC).

On the server also, I have 2 tasks running, one reading messages from the gRPC request stream and pushing them into a queue (`DataFlow.BufferBlock<byte[]>`), other processing messages from the queue, and writing responses to gRPC.

**The problem:**

If I disable (comment out) all the server processing code, and simply read and log messages from gRPC, there's almost 0 latency from client to server.

When the server has processing enabled, the clients see latencies while writing to grpcClient.

With just 10 active parallel sessions (gRPC Calls) these latencies can go up to 10-15 seconds.

**PS:** this only happens when I have more than one client running, a higher number of concurrent clients means higher latency.

---

The client code looks a bit like the below:

```cs
FileStream fs = new(audioFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1024 * 1024, true);

byte[] buffer = new byte[10_000];

GrpcClient client = new GrpcClient(_singletonChannel); // using single channel since only 5-10 clients are there right now
BiDiCall call = client.BiDiService(hheaders: null, deadline: null, CancellationToken.None);

var writeTask = Task.Run(async () => {
    while (fs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
    {
        call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new() { Chunk = ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer) });
    }
    await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
});

var readTask = Task.Run(async () => {
    while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
    {
        // write to log call.ResponseStream.Current
    }
});

await Task.WhenAll(writeTask, readTask);
await call;
```

---

Server code looks like:

```cs
readonly BufferBlock<MessageRequest> messages = new();
MessageProcessor _processor = new();

public override async Task BiDiService(IAsyncStreamReader<MessageRequest> requestStream,
    IServerStreamWriter<MessageResponse> responseStream, 
    ServerCallContext context)
{
    var readTask = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => {
        while (await requestStream.MoveNext())
        {
            messages.Post(requestStream.Current);  // add to queue
        }
        messages.Complete();
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var processTask = Task.Run(() => {
        while (await messages.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            var message = await messages.ReceiveAsync();  // pick from queue
            // if I comment out below line and run with multiple clients = latency disappears
            var result = await _processor.Process(message); // takes some time to process
            if (result.IsImportantForClient())
                await responseStrem.WriteAsync(result.Value);
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(readTask, processTask);
}
```

Comment: So when many clients write in the stream you see higher latency and you do not know why... is that it ?

Comment: Yes, that added with question why do these latencies go away when I comment out the processing logic? I have been assuming that since reading the gRPC messages is in a separate Task, processing of these messages should not affect the reading.

Comment: Also, I should mention, each clients opens their own stream (their own gRPC client) to talk to server. These gRPC clients use single underlying http2 connection (gRPC channel).

Comment: As a side note you are advised to switch from `var readTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>` to `var readTask = Task.Run(async () =>`, for reasons explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, I had it as `Task.Run` initially, but I was trying the `LongRunning` option (I had also removed all `await`s so the loop runs on a single thread), forgot to change it back to `Task.Run`, but point noted, changed in back now.

Comment: Changing `Task.Factory.StartNew` to `Task.Run` is an optimization for sure, but it does not affect the problem mentioned though. So the question remains open.

Comment: Take a memory dump when it is slow. It looks like a CPU oversubscription problem when you have too many CPU bound concurrent tasks running. How many concurrent downloads are you running and how many cores do you have on your machine how much MBit/s is going over the network?

Comment: @AloisKraus Not a lot of network, but the processing is CPU intensive, I'm running it on a 2 core container. I'll try to scale to have more power and see if that helps.

Comment: The clients are coming through another server app, having parallel sessions. The client (".net-core-rest-server-app") connects to gRPC server ("our main server") using localhost.

Comment: @AkashShrivastava: Then you have found the issue. If you have 2 cores but you run many CPU intensive tasks then you will need more cores if you want to stay fast. Scalability means adding more cores until-> { ( it is fast enough ), ( you become bankrupt )}. Efficiency means finding out what is so expensive by profiling your code and eliminate as much waste as possible.

Comment: Thanks @AloisKraus, that seems like something I should try next, I was hoping the delays to be there in `processTask`, but the `readTask` to remain active (maybe in a dedicated thread) so that gRPC reading part is not affected/delayed. Is that something reasonable to expect? because if not this is going to be way more expensive than I initially thought :D

Comment: The tasks you write are conceptually independent. But in reality your independent things need to run at a real CPU. There things become at runtime dependent if you have for one CPU more than one thing to execute at the same time. When you have more things to run than you have cores the OS scheduler (Windows,Linux does not matter) will need to choose which thread is next to run. The other too much work goes to the Ready Queue of the OS scheduler. Now your work ends up in a queue which is the delay you are seeing now.

Comment: Crystal clear. Thanks. Got too caught up in the superficial stuff and forgot the basics of OS.

Comment: @AkashShrivastava Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as it turned out, the problem was due to the delay in the number of worker threads spawned by the `ThreadPool`.

The `ThreadPool` was taking more time to spawn threads to process these tasks causing gRPC reads to have a significant lag.

This was fixed after increasing the `minThread` count for spawn requstes using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`. [MSDN reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of promising comments on the SO's initial question, but wanted to paraphrase what I thought was important: there's

1. a an outer async method that calls in to 2
2. Task.Run()'s - with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning option that wrap async loops, and finally a
3. returns a Task.WhenAll() rejoins the two Tasks...
   Alois Kraus offers that an OS task scheduler is an OS and its scheduling could be abstracting away what you might think is more efficient - this could very well be true and if it is

i would offer the suggestion to try and remove the asynchronous processing and see what kind of benefit difference you might see with various sync/async blends might work better for your particular scenario.
one thing to make sure to remember is that asynce/await logically blocks at an expense of automatic thread management - this is great for single-path-ish I/O bound processing (ex. needing to call a db/webservice before moving on to next step of execution) and can be less beneficial as you move toward compute-bound processing (execution that needs to be explicitly re-joined - async/await implicitly take care of Task re-join)